# Get the selected start and end cell location in SourceGrid

Tags: c#, range

[image]

From above picture, I want to get two results that return StartPoin(2,0) and EndPoint(4,2) respectively.

I had search google and stackoverflow, but found nothing.

Anyone have good idea?

Comment: Provide the code that you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `SelectedCells` property of the control you are using. This is an array of all of the selected cells.

Now you need to find the Cell with lowest `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` (that is the start point) and the cell with highest `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` (that is the end point).

It should be something like this (you find the variables that are used in your case.

Pseudo Code:

```
Cell StartPoint = null;
Cell EndPoint = null,
foreach(Cell cell in gridControl.SelectedCells){
   if(StartPoint == null)
      StartPoint = cell;
   else if(cell.RowIndex <= StartPoint.RowIndex && cell.ColumnIndex <= StartPoint.ColumnIndex ){
      StartPoint = cell;
   }
   if(EndPoint == null)
      EndPoint = cell;
   else if(cell.RowIndex >= EndPoint .RowIndex && cell.ColumnIndex >= EndPoint .ColumnIndex ){
      EndPoint = cell;
   }
}
```

Comment: I see you got the Selected Region. Check if there is already some properties that can give you the result you want. If not, well you'll have to find them manually like in my example above.

Answer (score 0):

After try many times.

I finally got the answer.

Using "[sourceGridName].Selection.GetSelectionRegion()" method.